# Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000 when fetching to Grafana Local API

Tags: javascript, windows, express, grafana, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Grafana local instance running on localhost:3000 on Windows and I'm fetching from an Express server running on my WSL. Everything is setup properly and the fetches to the Grafana API works for my team but not for me. Main difference is my Windows / WSL setup and their full Mac setups.

The error I receive when the fetch from my express backend goes to the Grafana localhost:3000

```
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
[1]       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
[1]     errno: -111,
[1]     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[1]     syscall: 'connect',
[1]     address: '::1',
[1]     port: 3000
[1]   }
[1] }
```

I've tried uninstalling Grafana, running Graf on different ports, changing .ini settings, turning off firewall, flushing DNS, etc.

I'm guessing the request is somehow being denied due to the WSL sending a request to Windows.

Comment: Are you sure that every step of this request supports IPv6?

Comment: I'm not sure, could you explain that to me? It's a standard express.js server with simple middleware.

Comment: Based on your error log, your request uses ipv6 (::1 is localhost there). Quite possible, that some network layer not fully supports it (or it is disabled somewhere). Try 127.0.0.1:3000